# Check if a record exists and return its ID if it was found or created?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, ezsql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Normalized DB insertions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551847/normalized-db-insertions)

Is it possible to do a single query that will look for a record and either return it's ID or insert it and return it's ID? Here's what I was thinking may work for this:

```
INSERT INTO firstname (id, name) VALUES (NULL,'$name') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name ='$name', id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)
```

If it helps, I'm using ezSQL and could just do a `$db->query("...");` then an `$id = $db->insert_id;` to grab the insert id and use it in a variable.

Comment: [You just asked this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551847/normalized-db-insertions)

Comment: I always downvote where a user asks the same question twice - never been sure why this happens though!

Comment: It was mostly because it had been a half hour with no answer on the first one and it had already passed the front page, then I posted this one and received an answer in 8 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own stored procedure which will check for existing record.

1. Try to retrieve the record by its id
2. Check if it is null, insert it
3. Otherwise you got the row

Comment: Currently, I have it selecting all the items in a database and putting them into an array, then doing an array_search to figure out if something is in the array or not. I'm trying to avoid this since there are now over 15 million records in the database, and that portion of the script is using a lot of memory and there could be 20 instances of this script running concurrently, which completely fills the memory of the system.

Comment: That's why I told you to write stored procedure

Comment: You don't need to do that, as instructed above, issue a SELECT statement to see if the row exists, if it returns no rows do an INSERT, your SQL in your question should be tossed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what do you need.

After calling INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... you just simply need to get last_insert_id() from database and this should be all.

Comment: Got it. I guess I'm confused about what this query does. If it's updating the ID of old records, won't that mess up any other tables that were referencing the old ID?